# How do I embed a plotly chart in a Notion document?

Tags: browser, embedded, iframe

I have a chart that I've made with plotly in RStudio. I can host it in an arbitrary location, with github or a place like shiny apps.

I'd like to make the plotly chart available from a Notion doc. I'm thinking I might embed it within an iFrame in the doc.

How do I add an iFrame with a plotly chart within a Notion doc?

Comment: I'd recommend posting this is on stackoverflow, not superuser

Comment: @mdrishan, no clue how to solve this one